# How to compare multi-value duplicates in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance

**Inputs**

I have a Dataframe with several columns. And list

```
proof_path = 

   #1  X  Y  #2  Z  #3  W  #4
0  p1  a  b  p2  c  p2  a  p3
1  p1  a  b  p2  c  p3  a  p1
2  p1  a  b  p2  d  p3  e  p4

rule = [('#1', 'X', 'Y'), ('#2', 'X', 'Z'), ('#3', 'W', 'Z'), ('#4', 'W', 'Y')]
```

In the above Dataframe, I want to examine whether each row is duplicated between `(#1, X, Y)`, `(#2, X, Z)`, `(#3, W, Z)`, and `(#4, W, Y)`.

For example In the row corresponding to index 0, `(#2, X, Z)` and `(#3, W, Z)` overlap `(P2, a, c)`.

In addition, `(#1, X, Y)` and `(#4, W, Y)` in row corresponding to index 1 overlap `(P1, a, b)`.
I'm going to drop rows that overlap between these multi-values from that dataframe.

My desired output is

**output**

```
proof_path = 

   #1  X  Y  #2  Z  #3  W  #4
2  p1  a  b  p2  d  p3  e  p4
```

And i tried as follows.

```
for depth in range(len(rule)-1):
    for i in range(1, len(rule)-depth):
        current_rComp = proof_path[[rule[depth][0], rule[depth][1], rule[depth][2]]]
        current_rComp.columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj']
        next_rComp = proof_path[[rule[i+depth][0], rule[i+depth][1], rule[i+depth][2]]]
        next_rComp.columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj']
        proof_path = proof_path[current_rComp.ne(next_rComp).any(axis=1)]
```

Although these methods were able to achieve desired results, they are inefficient by generating new Dataframes for each iteration. Is there a simple way to accomplish these tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a placeholder `mask` initially containing `False` values, essentially this `mask` will contain `True` if there any duplicates found in the corresponding row.

Generate length two `combinations` from `rule` list, then for each combination compare the slices of dataframe in order to create a boolean mask, now reduce this mask with `all` along `axis=1` and take the logical or of the reduced mask with the placeholder mask

```
from itertools import combinations

mask = np.full(len(df), False)
for x, y in combinations(rule, 2):
    mask |= (df[[*x]].values == df[[*y]].values).all(1)
```

Alternatively we can also wrap the above approach inside a list comprehension

```
mask = np.any([(df[[*x]].values == df[[*y]].values).all(1) 
               for x, y in combinations(rule, 2)], axis=0)
```

---

```
>>> df[~mask]

   #1  X  Y  #2  Z  #3  W  #4
2  p1  a  b  p2  d  p3  e  p4
```

Comment: but if a pair matches then we should stop there and remove the row. But with this we will compare with every rule then perform `any`. So Do you think writing a custom solution based on loops and conditions will work better than this?

Comment: @pygirl IMHO there is not much of a performance gain because if we remove the rows we still have to use boolean indexing every time in a loop to filter all such duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the rows that have duplicates on a subset of columns like -

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['#1', 'X', 'Y'],keep=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['#2', 'X', 'Z'],keep=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['#3', 'W', 'Z'],keep=False)
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for additional parameters.